# Custom field checkbox is greyed out (read only) on Void Payment

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom field on the Payments and Applications screen.  That when I void a payment I cannot edit my custom field on there.  The payment is in the balanced state and it lets me edit the Hold checkbox as well as the application date.  But I cant figure how to make my custom field editable as well?

Here is my DAC declaration on ARRegister Extension class

```
        #region UsrMAFOManuallyAddToRex


    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Manually Add Payments To Rex", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]

    public virtual bool? UsrMAFOManuallyAddToRex { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrMAFOManuallyAddToRex : IBqlField { }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
i am wondering why you need your field to be editable in a ***voided payment***.

When i checked the source of acumatica, i saw in the row selected event of ARPayment have the code which disables the whole cache [which may include your custom field too], this might be the reason why it is disabled in a voided payment.

If you really want to enable, you might need a custom code to enable the cache and disable the rest.